# How to loop try data in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Hello I have this data that I want to display in my UI.
I want to be able to loop try the data and display ProductTypeID and ProductTypeName in a li's

I would like to be able to loop inside jsx

I cant wrap my head around it, could you guys give me a hint? I am not really good working with data and looping tru it.

```
[{
  "ProductTypeID": 14,
  "ProductTypeName": "ItemName1",
  "ProductTypeImageUrl": "",
  "ProductTypeThumbUrl": "",
  "ProductTypeIconUrl": "",
  "IsActive": 1,
  "ProductTypeBlueImage": null,
  "Is3HourRent": null
}, {
  "ProductTypeID": 1,
  "ProductTypeName": ItemName2",
  "ProductTypeImageUrl": "",
  "ProductTypeThumbUrl": "",
  "ProductTypeIconUrl": "",
  "IsActive": 1,
  "ProductTypeBlueImage": null,
  "Is3HourRent": false
}, {
  "ProductTypeID": 10,
  "ProductTypeName": "ItemName3",
  "ProductTypeImageUrl": "",
  "ProductTypeThumbUrl": "",
  "ProductTypeIconUrl": "",
  "IsActive": 1,
  "ProductTypeBlueImage": null,
  "Is3HourRent": true
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render() {
 var data = [{
  'ProductTypeID': 14,
  'ProductTypeName': 'ItemName1'
 }, 
 {
  'ProductTypeID': 15,
  'ProductTypeName': 'ItemName2'
 }];

 return (<ul>
  {data.map((item) => {
   return (<li key={item.ProductTypeID}>
     <span>ID: {item.ProductTypeID}</span>
     <span>Name: {item.ProductTypeName}</span>
   </li>);
  })}
 </ul>);
}
```

Comment: both answers are correct and helped me understand how to map tru data in JSX. Thank you Alexey Pedyashev

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in your render method using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
render(){
  return <ul>
         {data.map(item => <li key={item.ProductTypeID}>{item.ProductTypeID}</li>)}
         </ul>
}
```

Comment: both answers are correct and helped me understand how to map tru data in JSX. Thank you goldbullet

Comment: I do like your answer a bit better because of the use or arrow functions